# Why does statically accessing class data members via pointers returns 1?

Tags: c++

Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class A {
    public:
        virtual ~A() {}
        int x,y,z;
};

int main (void)
{
    std::cout<<&A::x;
    std::cout<<&A::y;
    std::cout<<&A::z;
}
```

The output is:

> 111

What is the meaning of the output? Why is it 1? Are there any good reason to access class members via pointers (without created object)?

EDIT - Using:

```
printf("%p",&A::x);
printf("%p",&A::y);
printf("%p",&A::z);
```

prints: 4 , 8 and C.

It makes more sense now I guess.. (bytes)
But still, is there any use for that?

Comment: This seems interesting. [Tested sample](http://ideone.com/REupVk).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no `operator<<(std::ostream&, T)` defined for `T = &C::m`. Normally you'd get an error.

But instead, there is one for `T = bool` and an implicit conversion from a member-pointer to `bool`. So the output you're seeing is just the result of those pointers not being null (being converted to `true`).

Try this, for example:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int x, y, z;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha; // print boolean values as text

    std::cout << &A::x << std::endl;
    std::cout << &A::y << std::endl;
    std::cout << &A::z << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> true
>   true
>   true

---

Note that in the code `printf("%p", &A::X)`, you have undefined behavior.

The value for the `%p` specifier must be a `void*`, and there is no conversion from a member-pointer to a `void*`. Instead, what you have aliases (type-puns) to `void*`, which is undefined behavior. (Imagine that `sizeof(&A::x)` was 4 while `sizeof(void*)`was 64; nothing says this cannot be the case.)

You just have to come to terms with the idea that not all pointers can be viewed as integer offsets. That we can even print a pointer is implementation-defined: it could print "apple" for null, "pear" for one value, and "milk" for another if a (dumb) implementation wanted to. [I've touched on this difference between values and their representations before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167455/is-it-possible-to-hash-pointers-in-portable-c03-code/14169897#14169897).

And in this case, there is no output for the value *at all*. And that's okay, not all values have meaningful printed outputs. The most you can do is print out the individual bits:

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
auto print_bits(const T& value)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_standard_layout<T>::value>::type
{
    // it's okay to alias a standard-layout type as a sequence of bytes:
    const auto valueAsBytes = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&value);

    for (std::size_t byte = 0; byte < sizeof(T); ++byte)
    {
        // print in reverse order
        const std::size_t byteIndex = sizeof(T) - byte - 1;

        const unsigned char byteValue = valueAsBytes[byteIndex];

        for (std::size_t bit = 0; bit < CHAR_BIT; ++bit)
        {
            // print in reverse order
            const std::size_t bitIndex = CHAR_BIT - bit - 1;

            const bool bitValue = (byteValue & (1U << bitIndex)) != 0;

            std::cout << (bitValue ? 1 : 0);
        }

        std::cout << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

(I print the bytes and bits in reverse order because on my architectures this puts the least-significant bit on the right. I prefer to view binary values this way.)

This gives:

```
struct A
{
    int x, y, z;
};

int main()
{
    // example:
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
        print_bits(i);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // member-pointers:
    print_bits(&A::x);
    print_bits(&A::y);
    print_bits(&A::z);
}
```

Output:

> 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010
>   [...]
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 00111101
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 00111110
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 00111111
>
> 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000

There are no guarantees on what you see for the member-pointers.

Comment: Oh.. that makes sense. so is there any way I can see the real output? maybe by using Printf instead?

Comment: @Rouki: Depends on what you mean by "real" output.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I edited so I don't know if your comment still holds, but what do you mean?

Comment: Oh, no, my bad, you're pointing out that the `bool` overload is called. Correct. :)

Comment: @Rouki if you want to print out the internal representation of a pointer-to-member, use for example `std::cout << reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&A::x);`.

Comment: @Zyx2000 That's undefined behavior too - in fact, that shouldn't even compile. Not even reinterpret_cast can turn a pointer-to-member into an integer.

Answer (score 2):

`&A::x` creates a *pointer to member* of class `A`. A pointer to member is, in a way, a representation of the "position" of the member within the class. <s>What these numbers mean exactly depends on the particular implementation. I would guess that in your particular implemtation, it means `x` is on index 1 in the class (the virtual function table pointer being on index 0).</s> **EDIT** Actually, GManNickG's answer shows I was wrong with this assumption and it's just printing the pointer to member implicitly converted to `bool`.

Note that a *pointer to member* is **not** a pointer in the classic sense. You can't dereference a pointer to member directly. You always need a pointer/reference to an object to go along with it. Example (using your class):

```
int main()
{
  int A::*pm;  // pm is a pointer to member of A of type int
  A a;
  pm = &A::x;
  std::cout << a.*pm; //will output a.x
  pm = &A::y;
  std::cout << a.*pm; //will output a.y
  A *pa = &a;
  std::cout << pa->*pm;  //will output pa->y
}
```